Application using OLEDB connection with Oracle 19.18c generating dumps
I'm facing an issue with my application that uses an OLEDB connection with Oracle 19.18c. The application is generating dumps, and so far, we haven't been able to determine the cause.
Details:
Database: Oracle 19.18c
Connection Type: OLEDB
Issue: Application generates dumps unexpectedly
Environment: Windows 10
Dump Information:
SYMBOL_NAME:  msvbvm60+2fbb
MODULE_NAME: msvbvm60
IMAGE_NAME:  msvbvm60.dll
STACK_COMMAND:  .cxr 19e62c ; kb ; ** Pseudo Context ** Pseudo ** Value: 8da7f28 ** ; kb
FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  INVALID_POINTER_EXECUTE_INVALID_POINTER_READ_80000003_msvbvm60.dll!Unknown
OS_VERSION:  10.0.17763.1
BUILDLAB_STR:  rs5_release
OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x86
OSNAME:  Windows 10
IMAGE_VERSION:  6.0.98.48
FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {ef7a3a48-1a1e-255a-b34f-1f98aceb8063}
Followup:     MachineOwner
Steps Taken:
Checked the logs: We've reviewed the application logs and database logs but couldn't find any clear indicators of what might be causing the dumps.
Updated drivers: We've ensured that all drivers are up to date.
Reproduced the issue: The issue occurs intermittently and doesn't seem to follow a specific pattern.
"Note: Since I also use the application on a Windows Server, I cannot disable the generation of dumps there, so my storage is filling up every hour. I had to create a .BAT file to clean the dumps every 5 minutes."
I hope to find a solution to the problem, as the generation of dumps is filling my machine with dumps.
